# Draw in MS-Access (overcome object limit)

Tags: vba, ms-access, canvas, rendering, ms-access-2013

I'm placing hundreds and hundreds of boxes in dozens of carts with an optimization algorithm.

**Problem**:
How the boxes fit in the carts should be presented to the Access user visually and in print, and it should support moving individual boxes to other cart, by supplying a box ID and target cart ID and redraw. More ideally, via drag-and-drop.

**What have I tried**:

1. Rectangle objects on a Form. Hits the object limit after a few hundred boxes.
2. DuckDuckGone. Looked at Canvas and CanvasShapes. They seem to [not](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2e4fdcd9-6bcf-4122-9cc7-641dbc33d397/can-shapes-be-drawn-on-ms-access-forms?forum=accessdev) be canvases proper?
3. Looked at external tools to say, compose a PDF. It wouldn't be interactive, though, and data would have to be passed as XML or similar.

**Question**:
Is there a way to draw say, 1000 rectangles in any type of window (Form, Report, etc.) in Access 2013 using VBA?

*The rectangles are coordinate-based, so that it can't be presented as a table; you wouldn't see the physical dimensions of the carts and how the boxes fit in them.*

Answer (score 1):

In reports, you can, with the [`Report.Line` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/report-line-method-access).

But it will work (AFAIK) only in Print Preview and Print, not in Report view. So no interactivity whatsoever will be possible.

But I'm pretty sure it's your best option in Access.

Comment: I've looked into this and not yet been able to draw a line, but I've found documentation that will hopefully but not certainly let me overcome the problem. Because Access. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: I should add that in the end, the decision was made to not overcome the object limit, but to use two modal forms, one the sub-form of the other. In other words, I created "enough" objects (labels) in each form the cover its level of detail, transformed the ones to be shown and hid the remaining ones.